# nodejs, amqp infinite loop between publish and subscripe

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have two modules connected to rabbitmq.
Module A sends message to module B
Module B do some logic, and sends response back to A
Module A continues in work.
Module A:

```
var connection = amqp.createConnection(rabbitserver);
        connection.on('ready', function () {
            connection.publish('queue1', rabbitserver.login + ":" + param);
            connection.queue('queue2', {autoDelete: false}, function (queue) {
                queue.subscribe(function (msg) {
                    console.log("response recieved");
                    connection.disconnect();
                });
            });
        });
```

Module B:

```
connection.on('ready', function(){
    connection.queue('queue1', {autoDelete: false}, function(queue){
        queue.subscribe(function(msg) {
             var login, param, parts = msg.data.toString('utf-8').split(';');
             login = parts[0];
             fname = parts[1];
             result = somefucntion(login,param);
             connection.publish('queue2',result);
             console.log("send")
        });
    });
});
```

And when i start both, i get an infinite amount of messages "response recieved", and "send" in my consoles.

I have read amqp documentation but i cant find any solluton for this. And also is there a better way how to handle these simple responses?

Answer (score 0):

The connection automatically reconnects if there is a disconnect for *any* reason - including intentional disconnects.  You'll probably want to disable this behavior:

```
var connection = amqp.createConnection(rabbitserver, { reconnect: false });
```

Comment: When i do that i get ECONNRESET

Comment: @hnnn That's a known bug in the library. https://github.com/postwait/node-amqp/issues/300